# DT::DTOutput put a style only on the first line

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a dataframe df. I wanted to know if I could put a style only on the first line, I would like to highlight the line that counts missing values, and I want this line not taken into account when trying to sort a column by clicking on the little arrows.

```
app_ui <- function(request) {
 DT::DTOutput("data")
} 

app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Create df
  n_lines <- 10; n_col <- 10
  df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n_lines * n_col), ncol = n_col))
  df$years <- 2000:2009
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { for (j in 1:ncol(df)) { random_number <- sample(1:3, 1); if (random_number == 1) { df[i, j] <- NA } } }
  # Count NA for each columns
  df <- rbind(colSums(is.na(df)), df)
  output$data <- DT::renderDT(df, selection = 'none', server = TRUE, options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, scrollX=TRUE), rownames = FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which style you want to apply, you could use the rowname = 1 to target the row.

```
df %>% DT::datatable() %>%
  DT::formatStyle(0, target = 'row', 
              backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(1), c("red")))
```

[image]